# Decode base64 with white space

Tags: string, go, base64, url-encoding

I have a base64 encoded string i'm trying to decrypt with go. The string contains white spaces which should be ignored.
A sample code I'm trying:

```
s := "eyJ0aHJlZURTU2VydmVyVHJhbnNJRCI6IjEzZmU3MWQ0LWQxMGQtNDIyMC1hMjE2LTIwMDZkMWRkNGNiOCIsImFjc1RyY++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++W5zSUQiOiJkN2M0NWY5OS05NDc4LTQ0YTYtYjFmMi0xMDAwMDAwMDMzNjYiLCJtZXNzYWdlVHlwZSI6IkNSZXEiLCJtZXNzYWdlVmVyc2lvbiI6IjIuMS4wIiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlV2luZG93U2l6ZSI6IjAyIn0%3D"

out, err := base64.URLEncoding.DecodeString(s)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

This code returns:

> illegal base64 data at input byte 93

---

After changing the string padding, and using StdEncoding instead of URLEncoding:

```
s= strings.Replace(s, "%3D", "=", -1)
out, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

The output will be:

> {"threeDSServerTransID":"13fe71d4-d10d-4220-a216-2006d1dd4cb8","acsTrc���������������������������������������������������������������������������nsID":"d7c45f99-9478-44a6-b1f2-100000003366","messageType":"CReq","messageVersion":"2.1.0","challengeWindowSize":"02"}

---

How can I decrypt the string correctly?

Comment: "I have a base64 encoded string". No you don't. If you had one you could decode it without error. You have something else. Find out what you _actually_ have.

Comment: It is a base64 encoded string. Trying to use this site will decode the string correctly: https://www.base64decode.org

Comment: I would guess that the string is *supposed* to be using the 'URL and Filename safe' encoding described in https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4648 and that the plus signs are some kind of extraneous signal.  Other variations of base64 allow + in the encoding, or treat them as seperators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have is most likely "cut off" from a URL, and it is in URL-encoded form. So to get a Base64 string, you have to first decode it, you may use [`url.PathUnescape()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#PathUnescape) for this.

Once you have the unescaped string, you may decode it using the `base64.StdEncoding` encoder. Note that just because it is / was part of a URL, that doesn't make it a base64 string that used the alphabet of the URL-safe version of Base64.

Also the `+` signs in the middle of it are really just "junk". They shouldn't be there in the first place, so double-check how you get your input, but now that they are there, you have to remove them. For that, you may use [`strings.Replace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replace).

Final code to decode your invalid input:

```
s := "eyJ0aHJlZURTU2VydmVyVHJhbnNJRCI6IjEzZmU3MWQ0LWQxMGQtNDIyMC1hMjE2LTIwMDZkMWRkNGNiOCIsImFjc1RyY++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++W5zSUQiOiJkN2M0NWY5OS05NDc4LTQ0YTYtYjFmMi0xMDAwMDAwMDMzNjYiLCJtZXNzYWdlVHlwZSI6IkNSZXEiLCJtZXNzYWdlVmVyc2lvbiI6IjIuMS4wIiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlV2luZG93U2l6ZSI6IjAyIn0%3D"
s = strings.Replace(s, "+", "", -1)
var err error
if s, err = url.PathUnescape(s); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

out, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
```

Complete output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/4zD928Q-Sav)):

```
{"threeDSServerTransID":"13fe71d4-d10d-4220-a216-2006d1dd4cb8",
   "acsTransID":"d7c45f99-9478-44a6-b1f2-100000003366","messageType":"CReq",
    "messageVersion":"2.1.0","challengeWindowSize":"02"}
```

Note that the `+` sign is a valid symbol in the alphabet of the standard Base64, and you can even decode the Base64 without removing the `+` symbols, but then you get junk data remaining in the JSON keys in the result.

Answer (score 1):

The input string has three problems

First the + signs in the middle of it

Second there is garbage (a url encoded +) at the end

Third the string appears to not be valid Base64

To remove the plus signs in the middle, find the index of the start and finish and make a new string
To remove the garbage at the end, terminate the string earlier ( at index 249 of the fixed string)

There is a further problem with the string at index 148 of the fixed string, which I would guess is due to bad data

But the code fragment below shows how to overcome the first two things

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/base64"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := "eyJ0aHJlZURTU2VydmVyVHJhbnNJRCI6IjEzZmU3MWQ0LWQxMGQtNDIyMC1hMjE2LTIwMDZkMWRkNGNiOCIsImFjc1RyY++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++W5zSUQiOiJkN2M0NWY5OS05NDc4LTQ0YTYtYjFmMi0xMDAwMDAwMDMzNjYiLCJtZXNzYWdlVHlwZSI6IkNSZXEiLCJtZXNzYWdlVmVyc2lvbiI6IjIuMS4wIiwiY2hhbGxlbmdlV2luZG93U2l6ZSI6IjAyIn0%3D"


    a:=strings.Index(s,"+")
    b:=strings.LastIndex(s,"+")+1

    fixed:=s[0:a] + s[b:249]
    out, err := base64.StdEncoding.DecodeString(fixed)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        fmt.Println(fixed)

    }
    fmt.Println(a,b)
    fmt.Println(String(out))

}
```

Comment: maybe also interesting: removing the + signs and adding the = instead if %3D, then decoding and re-encoding with UrlEncoding gives a completely different String, starting with "ZXlKMGFISmxaVVJUVT"